# Inserting List data from Python into MongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am facing problem while inserting data from Python into MongoDb. I am able to connect to the MongoDB and read data (so connection problems are not there).

The input data the I have is in a list of list format (each comprising of 8 values separated by a | ), shown below :

```
Data = [array([ u”Col1 | u’Col2’ | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8”], dtype=object) ,
array([ u”Col1 | u’Col2’ | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8”], dtype=object)….]
```

What I want is to be able to insert it into MongoDB (and so make this into a Collection/Dictionary probably before loading). MongoDB requires us to have a Key:Value pair ready before inserting.

I did think of trying to break it in form of Key:Value pair by making it into a String and then Appending the header but it is not working out

```
for i in Data:
    # Convert List into String for data separation
    my_str = str(i)
    #To remove the [‘ and ‘] from the list into the string
    my_str = my_str.replace("[ '", "")
    my_str = my_str.replace("']", "")
    #print(my_str)
    #Break string into columns & Insert into MongoDb table here
    for x in my_str:
        strx= my_str.split('|')
        #print(strx)
        Col1 = strx[0]
        Col2 = strx[1]
        Col3 = strx[2]
        Col4 = strx[3]
        Col5 = strx[4]
        Col6 = strx[5]
        Col7 = strx[6]
        Col8 = strx[7]
    print(strx)
```

Output from above gives me an array of items (each having 8 elements in them) :

```
['[ u”Col1 ', " u’Col2’ ", ' Col3 ', ' Col4 ', ' Col5 ', ' Col6 ', ' Col7 ', ' Col8”]’]
```

I am stuck here and not sure what to do next.

Comment: I have been able to make a dictionary from the above and the dictionary data now looks like :

{
'Col1': ' v1 ', 'Col2': 'v2 ', 'Col3': ' v3 ', 'Col4': ' v4 ', 'Col5': ' v5 ', 'Col6': ' v6', 'Col7': 'V7', 'Col8': ' V8'}
}

Comment: i hope you are using pymongo. Have you tried the insert_many() method ? you can find a reference example at http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?_ga=1.24820794.1087864693.1464182583#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many

Comment: Thanks.
I was able to do this using INSERT_ONE() function present in PYMONGO package.

Comment: great. good . happy to help